# Can I remove the first original OS (Windows 10) from Ubuntu 16.10 dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall, windows-10

My Windows 10 was really slow, I was really frustrated so I decided to dual boot Ubuntu. I only put 100 Gigs on it because I wasn't sure if it was a great idea (I have 400gb in total). But it was a love at first test, so I wanna get rid (uninstall) of Windows 10 and put all the 400gb on Ubuntu. The question is, how do i go about doing that? thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can. :~)

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this process with virtually any live bootable media that includes `gparted` up to and including your Ubuntu 16.10 Live media that you likely used to install your system. If you still have that handy there is no need to create another bootable media. You can eliminate your Windows partitions from within your Ubuntu installation, but to resize your existing Ubuntu partitions you should boot from live media.

Comment: Resizing will take hours, but it's better than a reinstall, IMO. Just don't forget to backup the partition tables beforehand!

Comment: @jpaugh Won't the time to resize depend on the amount of actual data on the disk?

Comment: @wjandrea I would assume a number of variables. Speed of the drive,  percentage to shrink or grow, (number of inodes to add/subtract). It's late here and I'm tired so that's all I have at the moment.

Comment: @wjandrea No, it will depend on the original size of the partition. Gparted copies the entire partition to (the front of) the  new location, because it is not smart enough (or dumb enough, depending on perspective) to attempt to interpret the file-system inside the partition.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating a GParted live USB (http://gparted.org/livecd.php), and then use it to remove your windows partition, and grow your Ubuntu Partition

EDIT: You will probably  have windows reserved partitions too, such as the recovery partition. You can remove those as well, as long as you have/can make a windows recovery disk later, if you decide to go back.

Comment: Is there any risk of screwing (i don't mean accidentaly formatting the wrong partition, nobody is that dumb)

Comment: Well, yes people *are*  that dumb. But GParted is not difficult. Just make sure at all times that you are working with the correct partition and the correct drive.

Comment: It may not boot if GRUB was installed over the windows boot manager.
If that is the case, take a look here http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual&lang=C#gparted-fix-grub-boot-problem, and everything should work just fine.

Comment: Yes, there is risk in any moving or resizing of partitions (and GParted warns about it). Make sure you have backups of all the important personal files. Everything else can be reinstalled if the process fails at some point.

Comment: Actually it may well be that re-installing with the option "Erase and install..." is faster and easier than deleting, moving & resizing partitions and then "fixing" the bootloader... Your choice, just make sure you have backups.

Comment: @NicholasAgner I'm sure you're aware that although removing the Windows partitions can be done when running the installed Ubuntu, moving and resizing the Ubuntu partitions cannot be done because they are in used, mounted. You need to boot a live session from USB or DVD and run GParted from there. Please improve your answer by editing and adding this piece of information.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Yes, I forgot to add that in.

Comment: By removing you mean formatting it and deleting it making it unallocated space, right? @NicholasAgner

Comment: Yes, then growing your Ubuntu partition to take up the Unallocated space.


@Arynn

Comment: Does GParted necessairly need to be booted from usb? Is there a version of it that is just like a normal Windows partitioning software?

Comment: Yes and No. You can modify unmounted partitions with gparted but  it's easier (and safer) to do this work from a live media with your installations partitions unmounted. Backing up is highly recommended in case something  unexpected occurs.

Comment: @Arynn Unless you're okay with loosing *all* of your current partitions, backing up at least the partition table is a *really* good idea. It's easy to fat-finger, and having used `gparted` for years, I still make mistakes (yes, even despite how intuitive it is). Even backing up the entire disk can save a lot of frustration if things go wrong.

Comment: @Arynn But, if you are okay with the (easier) route of reinstalling Ubuntu, then there's no need to even use gparted; Ubuntu's installer has options to wipe the drive before installing.

Comment: @jpaugh Yeah, i reinstalled it. There was a ton of mess in the partitions, now it's just one big partition.

Comment: @Arynn In that case, you might consider accepting an answer, or providing a more detailed one, yourself. (The existing are pretty high-level.)

Comment: @Arynn Regarding the mess, I agree.  Partitions are always messy business! Every time I repartition, I realize I could have done something better, and just save that tip for the next fresh install. I used to keep 3-5 partitions, so I could e.g. save out `/home` in case `/` got nuked somehow (or I decided to reinstall.) Now, I'm relying on `btrfs` to do backups via `snapshots`.